# how to convert child - parent sql query to linq or lambda expression

Tags: linq, lambda, qsqlquery

i have tsql query. it is work fine. i want to convert it to linq query or lambda expression

```
DECLARE @myHID BIGINT;
SET @myHID = 1;

WITH tblChild AS
(
    SELECT *
        FROM wbs.WBS w WHERE w.ParentId = @myHID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT w2.* FROM wbs.WBS w2  JOIN tblChild  ON w2.ParentId = 
    tblChild.hID
    )
    SELECT 
        tblChild.hID, Unit.ID, w3.wbsName + ' * ' + tblChild.wbsName, 
        tblChild.FK_WbsBaseStructure_hID, tblChild.parentID, unitNumber, 
        unitTitle, FK_UsageItem_ID, usageTitle, nominalArea
   FROM tblChild
  inner join unit.Unit on tblChild.hID = Unit.FK_WBS_hID
  inner join unit.UsageItem on Unit.FK_UsageItem_ID = UsageItem.ID
  left join wbs.WBS w3 on tblChild.parentID = w3.hID
```

thank's

Comment: what have you attempted?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't notice you are using a recursive CTE in your SQL. Unfortunately, there is no good direct translation of a recursive CTE. The recommended approach is to create a Stored Procedure or View based on the recursive SQL and access that.

For translating SQL to LINQ,

1. Translate subselects as separate variables
2. Translate each clause in LINQ clause order, leaving monadic operators (`DISTINCT`, `TOP`, etc) as functions applied to the whole LINQ query.
3. Use table aliases as range variables. Use column aliases as anonymous type field names.
4. Use anonymous types (`new { }`) for multiple columns
5. Left Join is simulated by using a join variable and doing another `from` from the join variable followed by `.DefaultIfEmpty()`.
6. Replace `coalesce` with the conditional operator and a null test.
7. Use `Concat` for `UNION ALL` and `Union` for `UNION`.